# ROSJava installation problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to install rosjava in my labtop. And I follow the instructions

> http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/indigo/Source%20Installation

And in step 3.3, When I input:

> wstool merge https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/rosinstalls/master/my_custom_msg_repos.rosinstall

I got the error:

> ERROR in config: Unable to download URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/rosinstalls/master/my_custom_msg_repos.rosinstall]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

It seems the address is not existed any more. Anyone has the idea what problem is this? How can I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257166/rosjava-installation-problem/) by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems this source installation doesn't work, so I try the deb installation. Let's see what happened...

---

Originally posted by [vcdanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29640/vcdanda/) with karma: 38 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0